# Subtract files in folder A from folder B

Tags: terminal, macos

I've got folder A with 8000 images and folder B with 9000 images. Folder B contains the 8000 images from folder A as well as additional 1000 images. I would like to delete the 8000 images which are already in Folder A, leaving only the "new" 1000 images.

Does anyone know an elegant way to get the job done? (btw. I can not sort them by date and get the newer ones)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple bash script to do this::

```
for file in *.*; do if [ -f "/FolderA/${file}" ]; then rm "/FolderB/$file"; fi; done;
```

This script assumes you are already in FolderB, which is where you want to delete the files that already exist in FolderA.

You can tweak it if you know the extension of the image files (ie, .png, .gif, etc) and you have the exact folder names. So instead of `*.*` you can use `*.png` or `*.gif`.

**A MUCH safer version:**

```
for file in *.*; do if [ -f "/FolderA/${file}" ]; then mv "/FolderB/$file" ~/.Trash; fi; done;
```

This will **move** the file to the Trash.  Using `rm` is a one-way-street.  Once you hit enter on an `rm` command, it's done; that file is gone forever.  Move to the Trash to ensure you got the results you are looking for.

Comment: Missing `;` before `then`. Missing `fi;` before `done`

Comment: worked like a charm. fantastic

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the GNU `findutils` via homebrew, you can `cd` to `folderB` in the terminal and enter

```
echo rm $(find /path/to/folderA -type f -printf "%P\n")
```

Check the output. If it lists the files you want to get deleted, repeat without the `echo` to actually remove the files.

The default `find` of the system doesn't have `-printf`, but writing

```
echo rm $(find /path/to/folderA -type f -execdir {} \; )
```

(also issued from `folderB`!) should do the same job (can't test that here).

Comment: Is there a reason to not use find's `-delete`?

Comment: Because you don't want to delete the file you did find, but it's counterpart in the other folder. `-delete` has no such functionality, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a duplicate of folder A: A-copy.
- Open Terminal and enter `touch -mt 200001010000 /path/to/A-copy/*.*`
- Move the files from A(copy) to B and replace existing files there.
- Sort the files in folder B by modification date.
- Remove all files with the mod date January 1st, 2000 in folder B

This won't modify the mod dates of the original files in folder a.

---

If folder A already contains files with a January 1st, 2000 mod date choose another date in step 2.

Answer (score -1):

If folder B has all the images from folder A plus an additional 1000, then just delete folder A!

Simples!

However, if you have folder B has 9000 images and folder A has 9000 images but there is a disparity between them that folder B doesn't have all the images of folder A then use `diff` to find the difference.

Having said that, this will only be a file name difference. You might have two images that share the same name, which is an entirely different issue!

The code:

`diff -rq folder1 folder2`

> The r tells diff to look at each directory recursively, including subdirectories. The q switch sets diff brief mode. If we didn’t set brief mode, diff would not only tell you which files are different between the two folders, but also show the actual line-by-line differences for any text files that exist in both locations but are not identical.

Comment: If B=A'+X and A=A' removing A won't leave B with X...

Comment: Go and re-read the first part of b101's post. He states exactly what my first paragraph would solve.